# Complains about incompatible types

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a send email function in netbeans and it says

> "incompatible types: InternetAddress cannot  be converted to
>   InternetAddress[]".

When I write `InternetAddress[] address = new InternetAddress[10]();` it complains about a ; missing.

```
mailSession.setDebug(sessionDebug);
Message msg = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
InternetAddress[] address = (new InternetAddress(to));


msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address); 
msg.setSubject(subject);
msg.setSentDate(new Date());
msg.setText(messageText);
```

Comment: Try so: `InternetAddress[] address = new InternetAddress[]{new InternetAddress(to)};`

Comment: iF you want to create a new Array you do not have to use brackets at the end: `new InternetAddress[10];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`()` are not the right brackets to use for array initialization. Use `{}` instead:

```
InternetAddress[] address = {new InternetAddress(to)};
                         // ^                       ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
InternetAddress[] address = (new InternetAddress(to));


msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address);
```

Use

```
msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
```

Comment: It still doesn't work, complains about the same thing